# Doesn't an integral domain automatically imply that is it is of characteristic zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

I was reading about Ring Theory from the book Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein. I encountered the following definitions:

- *Definition 1*: If $a\neq 0$ is in a  commutative ring $R,$ such that there exists a $b(\neq 0)\in R$ such that $ab=0$, (,where $0$ is the zero element of $R$), then $a$ is called a *zero-divisor* of $a.$
- *Definition 2*: A commutative ring is called an integral domain if it has no zero-divisor.
- *Definition 3*: An integral domain $D$ is said to be of *characteristic*
  $0$ if the relation $ma=0,$  where $a\neq 0$ is in $D$ and where $m$ is an integer, can hold  only if $m=0.$

I feel that in fact all the integral domains $D$ are of  characteristic  $0,$ as since, $D$ is an integral domain it is never possible that $ab=0$ with $a\neq 0 ,b\neq 0.$ So, if say, $pq=0$ then, $p=0$ or $q=0.$ Again, if $p\neq 0$ then, surely $q=0.$

So, isn't it unnecessary to write Definition $3$ ? This is because Definition $2$ implies Definition $3$ we are just giving another name for integral domains, right?

Please correct me, if I am mistaken.

Comment: @infinitezero Maybe.

Comment: This would be true if any commutative ring contained the ring of integers, but it doesn't. And that's precisely the point of characteristic.

Comment: There is already a perfect answer, but the integrity domain thing means that we cannot have $ab=0$ for members $a,b\in R$ unless one of $a$ and $b$ is zero in $R$. The characteristic zero thing means that we cannot have $ma=0$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\in R$ unless either $m=0\in\mathbb{Z}$ or $a$ is zero in $R$. In writing $ma$ we are not using the ring multiplication, but are instead seeing $R$ as a **module** over $\mathbb{Z}$, so $m$ can be thought os as a sort of *scalar* that is multiplied by the element of the ring.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are mistaken: for example, the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (or more generally, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ prime) is an integral domain but does not have characteristic zero.

The point is that we have to distinguish between multiplication by "true integers" (which is relevant to calculating the characteristic) and multiplication by ring elements (which is relevant to integral domain-ness); inside $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the only nonzero element is $1$, so to check that it's an integral domain you just need to check that $1\cdot 1\not=0$.

It's a good exercise to show for integers $n \geq 2$ that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain iff $n$ is prime.

Comment: To slightly expand on this answer: the definition of the characteristic of a ring only uses the operation $+$ and the constants $0$ and $1$. On the other hand, the definition of an integral domain only uses the operation $\cdot$ and the constant $0$.