# How did they use this notation to prove the fact in my complete reference section?

Tags: ring-theory

I was studying Ring Theory and I think I have a couple of basic doubts.

First of all, let me write the definition of rings. It is,

*A set R is called an (associative) ring if there are two binary operations defined as addition "+" and multiplication ".", which  satisfies the following*:

- If $a,b\in R$ then $a+b\in R$
- If $a,b,c \in R$ then $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$
- If $a,b\in R$ then $a+b=b+a$
- If $a\in R$ then for all such $a$ there exists a $0\in R$ such that, $a+0=a$
- If $a\in R$ then there exist a $-a\in R$ such that, $a+(-a)=0$
- If $a,b\in R$ then $a.b\in R$
- If $a,b,c\in R$ then $a.(b.c)=(a.b).c$
- If $a,b,c\in R$ then $a.(b+c)=a.b+a.c$ and $(b+c).a=b.a+c.a$

Now, it appears that rings are nothing but generalizations of 'things' that happens in $\Bbb Z.$But there's a problem. The operations defined as addition throws some ambiguity in my mind.

Is $+$ just a mere arbitrary operation that might not have any link with normal addition (traditional) that we are familiar with from our childhood. I think this is indeed the case. It does not have to be the so-called addition in the traditional sense. Instead it might be, some arbitrary binary operation that we have just 'named' addition and nothing more. It might not necessarily have any link with the normal addition.

Same I think is valid in case of multiplication as well. Precisely '$.$' is an operation that might have  no link with the familiar process of multiplication. It is just some arbitrary operation that have been named as multiplication in $R.$

Now, here's the catch. While studying from "Topics in Algebra " by I.N Herstein, I found that in Chapter -3 which is dedicated to Ring Theory, there was a statement, "If $a\in R$ and $\underbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{q times}}=q.a,$ where $q(\gt 0)\in \Bbb Z.$

It appeared in the book as follows:

> We point out a striking difference between finite fields and fields such as
> the rational numbers, real numbers, or complex numbers, with which we
> are more familiar.
>
> Let F be a finite field having $q$ elements (if you wish, think of $J_p$ with its  $p$ elements). Viewing $F$ merely as a group under addition, since, $F$ has $q$ elements, $\underbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{q times}}=qa=0,\forall a\in F.$ Thus, in $F,$ we have $qa = 0$ for some positive integer $q,$ even if $a\neq 0. $ This certainly cannot happen in the field of rational numbers, for instance.

The thing that's bothering me in here, is precisely,  " $\underbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{q times}}=q.a$". It seems that a relation between the operations is established here between '$+$' and '$.$', **with no proper justification.**

The relation is familiar to us, when rephrased like this, " *If $a$ is added to itself $q$ times, then it is equivalent to multiplying $q$ by $a.$*" (In this quoted statement, the words "additions" and "multiplications" are used in the traditional sense that has been known to us since childhood.)

But when, addition and multiplication in a ring has **no link** with their traditional counterparts, how do hatch such a relation as this, $\underbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{q times}}=q.a$ above without defining any whatsoever relation between the operations previously ?
I tried to assume $\underbrace{a+a+...+a}_{\text{q times}}=q\times a,$ to avoid an abuse of notation. We needed to prove that $q.a=0$ not, $ q\times a=0$ but it appears they showed the later instead of the former.

Am I missing something?

**Additional reference:** Finally, here is the complete article picture from  Herstein 's book i.e

[image]

This caught me below the belt.

Comment: Even taking monoid, $a\cdot n$  is only shorthand for $\underbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{n times}}$ without defining multiplication (for $ n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Ring is just $\mathbb Z$-algebra.

Comment: The issue here is the same basic issue as in [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741183/isnt-an-integral-domain-implies-automatically-that-it-is-of-characteristic-zero): you have to separate ring elements from "external" integers. Note that $q$ is not a ring element.

Comment: When the ring is unital, we can identify  this product with a product in $R$.  In that context, the missing step is just the distributive property.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Even though $q$ is not a ring element but $q.a$ is an operation done which is defined in the ring. Then one more question arises in addition. Is $a.q$ well -defined?

Comment: @ThomasFinley Yes, we have a function $\times:\mathbb{Z}\times R\rightarrow R$ (where $R$ is our ring). This is similar to scalar multiplication in a vector space.

Comment: A unital ring $R$ is one that has an element $1_R$ such that $1_R \cdot a = a = a \cdot 1_R$ for every $a \in R$.  In that context, we can identify repeated addition with the product internal to $R$.  Without that, though, you need to fall back to Noah's comment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Pardon me, but at my level, we are not taught about what a vector-space is? But I still dont understand why does $a+a+...a=a.q$ ? A relation seems to be ignited out of nowhere between $.$ and $+$ out of air!

Comment: $\overbrace {a+a+a+\cdots +a}^{\text{n times}}$ is so called composite sum defined recurrently, so it is well defined without needing to have any other operation except sum.  B.L. van der Waerden, F. Blum, J.R. Schulenberg, Algebra, Volume I, Springer, 2003, pages 17, 36.

Comment: In case you haven't caught on, the multiplication appearing in $a \cdot q$ is _not_ the same, in general, as the product in $R$.

Comment: I am sure you understand the meaning of the axiom about the zero element but it is better to write it as: there exists a $0 \in R$ such that for all $a \in R$,  we have $a+0=a$

Comment: @BrianMoehring If you don't mind, you might consider taking a look at my now updated post. Thank you!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Please take a look at the post now. I have updated it.

Comment: $q.a$ is being *defined* as $a+a+\ldots+a$, where $q$ is a positive *integer* and $a$ is an element of the *ring* $R$. This is okay because there is no previous definition that it conflicts with. This is not the same as the ring multiplication $a.b$, where both $a$ and $b$ are elements of $R$, even though it uses the same symbol.

Comment: @Ted Can you post your comment as a formal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call the ring operations $+$ and $\cdot$ but assume no connection with the traditional arithmetic operations of the same names. So, the statements in OP regarding the usage of $+$ and $-$ is correct.

Now comes, the later part. Admittedly, that portion is ambiguous in Herstein and may be he left it to the readers to guess the "conventions" needed to use the symbols so.

I found a good explanation, regarding this  same issue in a book called,"A First Coutse in Abstract Algebra " by John B. Fraleigh, Victor J. Katz. It is quoted as follows:

> Continuing matters of notation,we shall always let $0$ be the additive identity of a ring. The additive inverse $a$ of an element of a ring is $-a.$ *We shall frequently have occasion to refer to a sum $$a+a+a\cdots +a$$ having n summands. We shall let this sum be  $\color{green}{n.a}$, always using the dot i.e $"."$.* **However, $n.a$ is not to be constructed as a multiplication of $n$ and $a$ in a ring, for the integer $n$ may not be in the ring at all.**
>
> If $n\lt 0$ , we let, $n.a=(-a)+(-a)+\cdots +(-a)$ for $|n|$ summands. Finally we define, $0.a=0$ for $0\in\Bbb Z$ on the left side of the equations and $0$ belongs to $R$ on the right side.

We may replace all the ocurrences of $ab$ or $pq$ or blah blah blah  in the picture with $a.b$ and so on using this particular notion in our head and then everything sorts out fairly.

Comment: It make impression, that you cannot see my comments.

Comment: @zkutch You referenced a different book? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your first statements are correct. We call the ring operations $+$ and $\cdot$ but assume no connection with the standard arithmetic operations of the same names.

However, certain connections arise as consequences of the ring axioms. First of all, standard natural numbers appear in our descriptions of symbolic expressions that denote ring elements: when we write $\underbrace{a+\dots+a}_{\text{$n$ times}}$, the $n$ is a natural number (the number of "$a$"s we're adding together), not an abstract ring element. The sum is a ring element, though, and we can define notation "$a\times n$" as shorthand for it. Notice that this $\times$ takes a ring element on the left and a natural number on the right, and returns a ring element. We assume no connection between this operation and the ring multiplication operation. Your text seems to have reused the symbol $\cdot$ for it, though, leading to confusion.

It turns out that there *is* a connection, though. If your ring has a multiplicative identity element (an element $e$ with the property that $a\cdot e=e\cdot a=a$ for all $a\in R$), then we can show using the ring's distributive axiom that $a\cdot(e\times n)=a\times n$. This motivates using the natural number $n$ as a name for the ring element $e\times n$ (and in particular, using the name $1$ for $e$). In this way, the ring includes a set of elements named by natural numbers, for which the ring multiplication operation $\cdot n$ coincides with the repeated addition operation $\times n$. In fact, the ring multiplication behaves on these elements the same way standard multiplication behaves on natural numbers (although it's possible for different natural numbers to name the same ring element).

It's a very useful exercise to work all these things out in detail, and you're right to be skeptical when notation is abused!

Comment: I see, the problem was with the abuse of notation. But isn't it wrong , to use that particular notation "$.$" in there ?

Comment: $a\cdot(e\times n)=a\times n$ is what I meant. The $\times$ denotes repeated addition. It's not until the following sentences (in which we name ring elements after natural numbers) that the expression $a\cdot n$ has meaning.

Comment: No, that was in response to your deleted comment. To your updated top comment: yeah, it's certainly wrong to use the ring multiplication symbol on a non-ring element without explaining what that means. Maybe the "$=$" you've quoted from your textbook is meant to be interpreted as a definition for "$a\cdot q$" when $q$ is a natural number.

Comment: @ThomasFinley "Isn't it wrong?" - there is no one setting or enforcing any rules on mathematics.  "Confusing for beginners" - certainly.  It might be better to start with a different symbol and later say that we can simplify things once we have found how it behaves.  It is very common.  Note that some people used $1_R$ for the multiplicative identity of the ring (if there is one) to avoid repeating the problem but it is very common not to do this and leave the meaning of $1$ to context.  Do you do any programming?  Many languages support "overloading".

Comment: @Karl If you don't mind, you might consider taking a look at my updated original post.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I took a look. Have you worked through the fourth paragraph of my answer? When a ring element is of the form $\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{\text{$q$ times}}$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity, we denote it simply by $q$. Then by the ring axiom of distributivity we have $a\cdot q=a\cdot(\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{\text{$q$ times}})=\underbrace{a\cdot1+\dots+a\cdot1}_{\text{$q$ times}}=\underbrace{a+\dots+a}_{\text{$q$ times}}$, so the two notions of multiplication agree.

Comment: In other words, for every natural number $q$, there is a ring element (which we also call $q$) such that $a\cdot q$ (ring multiplication) is equal to $a\times q$ (repeated addition), so we don't need a separate operation for repeated addition - it's already there in the ring multiplication. The author seems to assume you've internalized this.

Comment: @Karl Ok, so in short the whole story is: We declare the notation $q$ to be the ring element when the unit element in $R$ is added $q$ times, i.e $q=\underbrace {1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{q times}}.$ $q$ is in $R$ as $R$ is a group under $+$. So, using this notation, $a+a+...+a=a.(\underbrace {1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{q times}})=a.q$ using, the distributive property in $R.$ Now, the author has succesfully established that, $aq=0$ satisfying $q\in\Bbb N$ and $a\neq 0$. And this is what he wanted to show. The **main thing was the notation of $q=\underbrace {1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{q times}}.$**. If this was

Comment: @Karl (continued) written explicitly, it would remove all confusions. Did I get you correctly? Will you mind adding your last two comments in the answer? As comments here, gets deleted over time. I will be glad to accept it! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The notational conventions used in many abstract algebra textbooks is often ambiguous.

Recall that if $G = (S,e,\cdot)$ is a group, $a \in S$, and $p \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$ 
a^p
:= 
\begin{cases}
a, & p =1 \\
a\cdot a^{p-1},&  p > 1. 
\end{cases}
$$ By convention, $a^0 := e$. It can be shown, via induction, that $(a^p)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^p$, so $a^{-p} := (a^p)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^p$.

If $G= (S,\mathbf{0},+)$ is an *additive* group, the notation changes: e.g., $a^p$ is written as $pa$ and $a^{-1}$ is written as $-a$. Notice that the convention $a^0 = e$ becomes $0a=\mathbf{0}$. Recall that if $G$ is a finite group, i.e., $\vert S \vert = q$, then $a^q = e$ (this is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem). In an additive group, this becomes $qa = \mathbf{0}$, which justifies the claim in the OP's post.

> The thing that's bothering me in here, is precisely, "$\underbrace{a+a+a+\cdots +a}_{\text{q times}}=q.a$". It seems that a relation between the operations is established here between '$+$' and '$.$', **with no proper justification.**

This notation becomes problematic in a ring because, (e.g.) if $a \in R$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $na$ looks like multiplication. However, it is understood that the latter is *exponentiation* with respect to addition.